# width for the remaining place

Tags: html, css

How can I make inner div auto width according to img width?

```
<div style="width: 900px">
   <img src="img.png" width="No one knows. All time different." />
   <div>I want to make this block auto width according to img width</div>
</div>
```

I need IMG and inner DIV show INLINE.

This is what I really have: http://jsbin.com/beyijira/1/edit

Comment: have you tried float: left; both?

Comment: @Prashank can you show me?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/loxiruni/1/edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Better solution probably...

-- HTML

```
<div style="width: 700px">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
   <div class="content">
           I want to make this block auto width according to img width
   </div>
</div>
```

-- CSS

```
.image {
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
}
.content {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6N3tH/

--- OLD SOLUTION -----

Hmm..is this what you want? Try it...

-- HTML

```
<div style="width: 700px" class="clearfix">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
   <div class="content">
           I want to make this block auto width according to img width
   </div>
</div>
```

-- CSS

```
.image {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.content {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20px;
}
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Not my most lovable solution but it works :|

http://jsfiddle.net/2MQfn/

Answer (score 0):

Use this markup

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 900px">
   <div class="outer">
      <img src="img.png" width="No one knows. All time different." />
      <div class="inner">I want to make this block auto width according to img width</div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clear{clear:both;}
.outer{float:left;}
.inner{width:100%;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ByPK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 900px">
  <div class="main">  
   <div class="outer">
  <img src="img.png" width="100px" />
</div>    
  <div class="inner">I want to make this block auto width according to img width</div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
.main{display:table; width:1%;}
.outer{display:table-row;}
.inner{width:1%; display:table-row;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/25VV5/3/)